# error in Generic

Tags: c#, generics

Why following code does not work?

```
public void getData<T>(T ConnectionStirng)
{
    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);  \\compile error
}
```

Comment: is that the source code or did you just type this up?

Comment: Why are you using generics here anyway ?

Comment: Please always copy the actual code from your program when posting code snippets. The code as shown would never be a part of a real program because it has numerous problems on its own. Wrong way on comment slahses, "ConnectionStirng" incorrectly spelled. Top that off with not posting the actual error message, just that the compiler doesn't like it, and you're just creating an example of how not to post.

Answer (score 7):

Because the `connectionString` should be a string, not `T`.

The `OleDbConnection` class only has two constructors:

```
OleDbConnection() // Empty parameter list
```

and

```
OleDbConnection(string connectionString) // takes a connection string
```

When you compile by trying to pass in an object of type T, there's no way for the compiler to know what type that is (since it's not being used in context at that point).

Therefore, since T isn't guaranteed to be a string...there is no overload for the OleDbConnection that matches the parameters you're calling it with.

In this case, since there's no return value and the connectionString must be of type string...there's no need for generics at all. It can be simply written as:

```
public void getData(string connectionString)
```

Unless you're trying to return a collection of data of type T, then it would look like:

```
public IEnumerable<T> getData<T>(string connectionString)
```

**Edit**

...and none of that addresses the fact that your parameter name doesn't match what you're trying to pass to the constructor or the fact that the slashes in your comments are backwards.

Comment: +1! This actually made me smile, and still. :)

Comment: wow, who upticked the superfluous 'what is the correct code'?

Answer (score 3):

Because **OleDbConnection** expects a string and you've passed a T.

Looking at the code you don't actually need generics. Surely this is enough:

```
public void getData(string connectionString)
{
   OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because OleDbConnection's constructor only takes a string.